# How to make image fully scrollable after rotate it left and right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on implementation simple image viewer component. I need only to be able to rotate and zoom image. However, I met an issue, that after this transformation even appeared scrollbar does not fully allow to see the whole image.

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Image Viewer</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <img id="viewer" src="CHARGES_10 16 2013 10 17 2013_page-0003.jpg" alt="Viewer">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="controls">
    <button onclick="zoomIn()">Zoom In</button>
    <button onclick="zoomOut()">Zoom Out</button>
    <button onclick="rotateClockwise()">Rotate Clockwise</button>
    <button onclick="rotateAntiClockwise()">Rotate Anti-Clockwise</button>
    <span id="currentPage">Page: 1</span>
    <span id="totalPages">of 5</span>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**css:**

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .image-container {
    overflow: scroll ; /* Enable scroll bars when content overflows */
    width: 80%;
    max-height: 80vh;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a border for visibility */
  }
  
  

  .image-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  
  #viewer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  }
  
  
  .controls {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  
  button {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
```

**Javascript:**

```
let currentZoom = 1;
let currentRotation = 0;

function zoomIn() {
  currentZoom += 0.1;
  updateTransform();
}

function zoomOut() {
  currentZoom -= 0.1;
  updateTransform();
}

function rotateClockwise() {
  currentRotation += 90;
  updateTransform();
}

function rotateAntiClockwise() {
  currentRotation -= 90;
  updateTransform();
}

function updateTransform() {
    const viewer = document.getElementById('viewer');
    viewer.style.transformOrigin = 'center center';
    viewer.style.transform = `translate(${50 * (currentZoom - 1)}%, ${50 * (currentZoom - 1)}%) scale(${currentZoom}) rotate(${currentRotation}deg)`;
  }
```

[tag:user:1427878]
[tag:user:21341168]

I need source file in html,css,js

I know, that transform operations are applied to coordinate system, not to image itself. However, I don't know what to do with transform-origin in such case, plus it seem to me like it's not a proper way to do such obvious and simple thing. It feels like there should be simple solution.